# GitHub Actions output not showing in my next step when calling it

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to do a simple echo that just shows the message with the output when the step above fails or succeeds but it shows up blank.

Part of my YML file looks like this:

```
      - name: Create Unit Test File
        run: dotnet test .\app\tests --no-restore

      - name: Success Output
        if: success()
        id: step_pass
        run: echo "exit_code=0" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Failure Output
        id: step-fail
        if: failure()
        run: echo "exit_code=1" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Show Exit code
        if: always()
        run: echo "The exit code is ${{ steps.step-fail.outputs.exit_code }}"
```

The message when run shows like this when Create Unit Test File fails: `Run echo "The exit code is "`

I want to see something like this: `Run echo "The exit code is 1"`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to use `os: [ubuntu-latest]`   not windows